# change the fetched json data using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I've fetched the json data, which look something like this:

```
 {
     "id": "154",
     "user_id": "1445674241",
     "title": "Power of one",
     "content": "<p><img style=\"display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\" src=\"/photo.png\" alt=\"Power of one\" width=\"455\" height=\"567\" /></p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>One is really powerful, you are one, God is one, earth is one. Love the one.<img style=\"display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\" src=\"/photo.png\" alt=\"Power of one\" width=\"455\" height=\"567\" /></p>",
     "num_views": "0",
     "votes_up": "1",
 }
```

I want to change the attributes of all img tags(like append src, change height & width) using angular js.

I am also rendering the html code using ng-bind-html in my controller. And the function for that is :

```
 $scope.renderHtml = function (html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
};
```

Help me out to change the attribute of img tags.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Want to change the attributes of img tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get your hands dirty working directly on `data.content` string...
Something like this:

```
var newWidth = 123;
data.content = data.content.replace(/(img.*?width=")(.*?)(")/g, function(c1, c2, c3) { return c1 + newWidth + c3; });
```

Comment: what is c1,c2 and c3??

Comment: the contents of each of the three capture groups (`(...)`) we used in the example...  Perhaps you'll find useful reading http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create some kind custom filter for that, for ex- if I'm getting a youtube link from my data input and I want to modify it before embedding in my page-

```
myApp.filter('trustedURL', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(input) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(input);
    };
}]);

myApp.filter('youtubeEmb', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(input) {
        var shortYou = input.match(/youtu.be/g);
        if(shortYou){
            return input.substring(0,input.indexOf('?')).replace(shortYou,"youtube.com/embed");
        }else{
            return input.substring(0,input.indexOf('&')).replace("watch?v=","embed/");
        }
    };
}]);
```

my HTML-

`<iframe src="data.uri | trustedURL | youtubeEmb"></iframe>`

Here it was url, similarly you can create some function for img tag attrs.